# Simple Update Query Not working - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

Here is my Update Query in Laravel

```
$do = DB::table('pipo_orders')
            ->where('id', 1)
            ->update(array('clientcopyimage' => 1));
```

The Table name is `pipo_orders` while i execute the query no change is happening to that particular coloumn.

Is there any basic mistake in the Query

[Here is the Documentation i followed.](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#updates)

Comment: what is field `clientcopyimage` datatype?

Comment: It is of **varchar**

Comment: then you need to quote input value like `array('clientcopyimage' => "1")` if field datatype `varchar, enum` probably it should work

Comment: @Girish Of course not. BizDev, the code is correct. Make sure that you're checkning right table/column/connection, also what does it return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said the datatype for `clientcopyimage` is `varchar`, then you should quote your value like [Girish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/926333/girish) said

```
$do = DB::table('pipo_orders')
            ->where('id', 1)
            ->update(array('clientcopyimage' => "1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If field data type `varchar` or `enum` then need to quote input value.

```
->update(array('clientcopyimage' => "1"));
```

otherwise Library will behave input value as `numeric`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your **where** chain method

should have equal sign '=',

```
$do = DB::table('pipo_orders')
        ->where('id','=',1)
        ->update(array('clientcopyimage' => 1));
```